# How to show virtual keyboard dynamically in delphi xe5

Tags: ios, delphi, keyboard, delphi-xe5

Within an OnClick event for a button, I have the following code:

```
KeyboardService.ShowVirtualKeyboard(SomeEditTextField);
```

It runs, and no errors, however, nothing happens. I would expect this to show the keyboard for the corresponding control. What am I doing wrong ?

Delphi xe5, developing for iOS.

update: 
My core problem is - I am using an application that makes use of a iOS supported bluetooth scanner which acts as keyboard input. On the scanner (but not all of the scanners we will be using) there is a button to toggle the keyboard state. E.g., switch between scanner input and showing virtual on screen keyboard. I want to simulate this same functionality but on the applicaiton UI itself, to compensate for the possible scanners that do not have this 'toggle' button. I've been told... that calling the above procedure will override and display the on screen keyboard even if a hardware input is present.

UPDATE 11/1: So.. I have by chance come across some interesting information. When pressing the escape does the exact 'toggle' feature I want. Now the question is, how do I simulate pressing the escape key from a Tbutton ? How would I send that 'escape' key to the application?

Comment: What is `ShowVirtualKeyboard()` returning - True or False?  If False, then it was not able to show the keyboard, which can happen for a couple of different reasons.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of `ShowVirtualKeyboard()` for iOS, it looks like it calls `becomeFirstResponder()` (which normally displays the keyboard - but is not guaranteed if `becomeFirstResponder()` is overridden to do something else) on the parent Form rather than on the specified text field, so that is likely why the keyboard is not displaying correctly. I am no iOS developer, or a FireMonkey user, but that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Yeah, no I am running under debug mode and it errors out. I can't even trace into the function currently.

Comment: See if this discussion on the Embarcadero forums helps you: [show/hide virtual keyboard on iOS](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=571526)

Comment: I've already seen that. My core problem is: I am using an application that makes use of a iOS supported bluetooth scanner which acts as keyboard input. On the scanner (but not all of the scanners we will be using) there is a button to toggle the keyboard state. E.g., switch between scanner input and showing virtual on screen keyboard. I want to simulate this same functionality but on the applicaiton UI itself, to compensate for the possible scanners that do not have this 'toggle' button.

Comment: You may have to copy the source code of `ShowVirtualKeyboard()` from `FMX.Platform.iOS.pas` into your own code and then tweak it to make it work. Like I said, at first glance, it does not look implemented correctly to me, but I might be wrong. Try calling `becomeFirstResponder()` on the Text field itself rather than the `UIView` of the parent Form`.